# 401 error while consuming WCF services from Android

Tags: c#, android, wcf

I have to consume a certain WCF service from Android. I am sending a POST request and posting certain parameters. While doing this I get a 401 Unauthorized Error. If I post the same values to the same url from POSTMAN (Google chrome extension) the request gets posted perfectly. The similar happens when I try to do a GET request.

Here is my code for POST:-

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.AddStatusEndpoint);

            try 
            {
                // Set header with AccessToken
                httppost.setHeader("Authorization", accessToken);

                //Add parameters as Form encoded
                //
                /*
                */

                List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>(5);
                   nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",username));
                nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", comment));
                nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", status));
                nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sTime", startTime));
                nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location",""));


                AbstractHttpEntity entity;
                entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);

                entity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
                entity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                //Fetch the response
                HttpResponse responsenext = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                HttpEntity entitynext = responsenext.getEntity();
                AddedResult= EntityUtils.toString(entitynext);

                JSONArray jObject;
                try 
                {
                    jObject = new JSONArray(AddedResult);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jObject.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject(i);

                        String name= menuObject.getString("name");
                        String status= menuObject.getString("status");
                        String starttime= menuObject.getString("sTime");

                        resultList.add(new FinalResponse(name, status, starttime, starttime, starttime, "true"));



                    }

                }
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Does the WCF service use any authentication?

Comment: @ArunGhosh yes it does. When Authenticated I get a accesstoken (I am getting this fine), which I pass as header in the mentioned request. I used the same access token i get in my device and posted from postman, that works fine, but the same does not work from the device.